# Linking lots of .libs to make a DLL: unresolved external symbol _DllMainCRTStartup

Tags: dll, build, linker

I'm performing the (terrifying) task of building LLVM 3.3 on windows and I have got to the stage where I have a load of `LLVM*.lib` files. I want to link them together to one huge shared DLL but am struggling (this is my first time linking stuff on windows). I've tried:

```
link /DLL /MACHINE:X64 /OUT:LLVM3.3.dll LLVM*.lib
```

but to no avail. It errors with:

```
LINK : warning LNK4001: no object files specified; libraries used
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DllMainCRTStartup
LLVM3.3.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

The internet suggested adding the `/DEFAULTLIB:corelib` switch, so I did that but again it has problems:

```
> link /DLL /MACHINE:X64 /DEFAULTLIB:corelibc /OUT:LLVM3.3.dll LLVM*.lib

LINK : warning LNK4001: no object files specified; libraries used
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'corelibc.lib'
```

How do I do this?

---

**EDIT:** I managed to fix the above problem, by implementing an empty `DllMain` and making an `EmptyDllMain.obj` from it:

```
#include <windows.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, 
                   DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, 
                   LPVOID lpReserved
                 )
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

and then trying:

```
link /DLL /OUT:LLVM3.3.dll LLVM*.lib EmptyDllMain.obj
```

but the DLL I get out is just 8kb - it seems to have missed out the many megabytes of LLVM libraries! How do I get them included?

---

**EDIT2:** I solved the LLVM compilation on Windows problem, take a look at this [document on github](https://github.com/CRogers/LLVM-Windows-Binaries/blob/master/compiling.md).

Comment: The reason the DLL is tiny is that lib files are only linked in if they are needed to satisfy references.  You don't have any - so nothing is linked.  Options are 1.  Write a DEF file to create references; 2. Use `-WHOLEARCHIVE:<lib>`

Answer (score 3):

I had this once while linking one lib with a wrong platform set together (X86 to X64). Make sure all the LLVM*.lib are build and linked with the correct toolchain:

```
[...]\Microsoft visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64\ cl.exe and link.exe
```

which you get by calling

```
"%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
```

Also I had similar problems when mixing MT and MD CRTs, I recommend you stick to

```
/MD (or /MDd for debug)
```

when compiling the objects for any of the LLVM*.lib (and any other objects from other external libraries you link into these).

[edit]

And kick out that ugly EmptyDllMain.obj !

[/edit]

Comment: I had the same issue and it was driving me crazy. In my case "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat" amd64_x86 was the trick to reset the toolchain.

Comment: "And kick out that ugly EmptyDllMain.obj " so how to solve the linker error then instead?

Answer (score 2):

If you manually entered the `_DllMainCRTStartup`, be sure you spelled it (watch case) correctly.  I had `_DLLMainCRTStartup` and took a while to catch why I still received the linker error.  For Windows CE, the required link lib is `corelibc.lib`.

Comment: Excellent answer, but what is the library for visual c++ 6.0 and below *(corelibc have an another name)* ?

Answer (score 0):

remove lib files from "ignore specific default libraries" from "Linker->Input" on project properties